# Find focus in OS X

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, macos

Is it possible to create an app for the mac (and iphone afterwards) that does something when it detects that the focus is on a certain object in the screen?

Meaning, the program runs in the background, and when it detects that the focus (or cursor) is on an edit box, it will run something.

Hopefully I made myself clear!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this on the mac by using the Accessibility Framework.

Note that users will have to manually enable assistive devices and you will not be able to distribute your app on the Mac App Store due to Apple's soon-to-be-implemented sandboxing restriction.

On iOS, you can detect focus to certain but not all elements using specialized delegate methods such as `textViewDidBeginEditing:`. That said, as users use taps to navigate iOS apps most of the time, simple tap handling seems like a much better approach.

Comment: Can i use textViewDidBeginEditing or any tap handler on other running apps, other than mine?

Comment: No. On an iPhone that is not jailbroken, Apple strictly prohibits apps interfering with other apps in any way.

Answer (score 2):

On the iPhone, you can only detect focus within your own app, there's no way to observe other apps from the background.

On the Mac, as [0x90](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9122662/573626) noted, the closest you'll get are the Accessibility APIs. The [UIElementInspector sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/UIElementInspector/Introduction/Intro.html) may help you to get started.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll look into the element inspector